# Unable to read the environmental variable in the contect of VueJS

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I am trying to use the environment variable in my component. But it works initially when i use the variable, but then it throws an error.

**Component.vue**

```
website: 'testing-hard-reality'
```

The code works absolutely fine when it is hardcoded, shown above. If the environment variable is used rather the hardcode i get an error

**.env.local**

```
VUE_APP_WEB_SITE: 'testing-hard-reality'
```

In the component the variable is used as:

```
website: process.env.VUE_APP_WEB_SITE
```

In my console i am getting the error as

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "Error: WebSite name is not set"

Please do tell me what to do.

Comment: Full reproducible demo, please

Comment: env variable should be like `VUE_APP_WEB_SITE=testing-hard-reality` in `env.local` file. its separated by `=` operator => `key=value`

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh i have changed that, but still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create in the same level of src folder a file

`.env.development.local` is used for working locally

`.env.production.local` is used for production

Add in the file your env variable

```
VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE_NAME = my-value-here
```

`VUE_APP_*` part is important because all env variables in vue project needs to start with this prefix.

Now to get access on this value do:

```
process.env.VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE_NAME
```

**IMPORTANT** STEP

Whenever you modify the `.env` files you have to stop your server and start it again in order to get the env changes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using vue-cli to build your vue project. In the vue-cli docs, I found the grammar of env.local would be

```sh
VUE_APP_WEB_SITE=testing-hard-reality
```

not your demo: `VUE_APP_WEB_SITE: 'testing-hard-reality'`

ref: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: @app_er We need a full reproducible demo to find what happend

Comment: I just tried your answer and still i am getting the same error, so now what exactly you wanted ?

Comment: Hi, please make a simple github repo which can reproduce your problem, so I can debug in my local machine.