# .env Not returing all character in vue app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, environment-variables

In my .env my variable is defined as
**VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET=$2a$10$tgYzYgMgTsdfLlRFtkd9IeEc2W4v/0EuG1uf05ztQARqhsf3esr9D5Zi**

So , when i am trying to access variable from .env as
**process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID**,
it only returning **"/0EuG1uf05ztQARqhsf3esr9D5Zi"** in place of
**"$2a$10$tgYzYgMgTsdfLlRFtkd9IeEc2W4v/0EuG1uf05ztQARqhsf3esr9D5Zi"**.

How can i solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes around the string in env file like VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET="$2a$10$tgYzYgMgTsdfLlRFtkd9IeEc2W4v/0EuG1uf05ztQARqhsf3esr9D5Zi" ?

Comment: yes! Still not working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, add a backslash before $ in your key.

Try this `VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET="\$2a\$10\$tgYzYgMgTsdfLlRFtkd9IeEc2W4v/0EuG1uf05ztQARqhsf3esr9D5Zi"`

Answer (score 0):

wrap the environment variable value in single quote
`VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET='$2a$10$tgYzYgMgTsdfLlRFtkd9IeEc2W4v/0EuG1uf05ztQARqhsf3esr9D5Zi'`

Comment: true - but there are special characters in the value itself which will cause the export command to neglect subsections from the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Write the value in double quotes, like `VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET="$2a$10$tgYzYgMgTsdfLlRFtkd9IeEc2W4v/0EuG1uf05ztQARqhsf3esr9D5Zi"` in .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in my answer here in case it helps you. [Unable to read the environmental variable in the contect of VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65774043/unable-to-read-the-environmental-variable-in-the-contect-of-vuejs/65774975#65774975)

Probably your issue is that you do not rerun your server after changing the env variables. Every time you change the .env you need to rerun the server in order to see the new changes.